Is there a machines module in Anaconda Spyder or a an alternative?
I am creating a new class and saved the data to a .py file.
I read that I could call that class from such file using the machines module.
I am using Anaconda Spyder and it seems there is no such module. moreover, where I read it seems the author of the article is using 'MicroPython'.
see code below. Notice that 'some_tests' is the name of my .py file containing the class code - 'test'
thank you.
from machines.some_tests import test


Using the os module, I set my CWD to where the .py file was saves and used the following:
from some_tests import test
and it seems to work.
